# Is AVTUR the same as JP-1 fuel?

Tags: fuel

I read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_fuel#Military_jet_fuels):

> JP-1 was an early jet fuel specified in 1944 by the United States government (AN-F-32). ... It was also known as avtur.

Is AVTUR the same as JP-1 fuel, and the term "AVTUR" is just a nickname?

Comment: `AVTUR` stands for **AV**iation **TUR**bine Fuel and is equivalent to JP-1, at least in the UK.  [This](http://www.csgnetwork.com/jetfuel.html) might help.

Comment: @Simon maybe post that as an answer?

Comment: Hardly seems worth it, but OK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AVTUR stands for **AV**iation **TUR**bine Fuel and is equivalent to JP-1, at least in the UK and in as much as JP-1 no longer exists.  I believe that the US military equivalent is JP8 which is Jet-A1 with additional additives, which differs from commercial Jet-A only by a lower freezing point.

[Here is the relevant NATO Def Stan (Defense Standard)](http://www.seta-analytics.com/documents/Defstan_91-91_R7.pdf) for Avtur with is the same defstan as for Jet-A1.

[This link](http://www.exxonmobilaviation.com/AviationGlobal/Files/WorldJetFuelSpecifications2005.pdf) to an Exxon document gives a great deal of information for various aviation fuel oils.

[EDIT]

[From here:](http://www.shell.com/global/products-services/solutions-for-businesses/aviation/shell-aviation-fuels/fuels/types/military-jet-fuel-grades.html)

> JP-8 is the military equivalent of Jet A-1 with the addition of
>   corrosion inhibitor and anti-icing additives; it meets the
>   requirements of the U.S. Military Specification MIL-T-83188D. It is
>   the dominant military jet fuel grade for NATO airforces. The UK also
>   have a specification for this grade namely DEF STAN 91-87 AVTUR/FSII
>   (formerly DERD 2453). NATO Code F-34.

Comment: I suspect this answer is confusing JP-1 (which is obsolete and no longer used) with Jet A-1.  The military kerosene-based jet fuels are JP-5 and JP-8, while JP-4 (the old USAF jet fuel) is a wide-cut fuel...

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject That wasn't my intention and I've re-read the answer.  I can't see where the confusion is. Please point it out to me.  Thanks.